# How I keep run the program

Tags: python, function, if-statement, python-3.x, control-structure

I'm here again.I'm newbie and I have some questions.

I have a code like that,

```
enter = input("Please type something: ")

if enter == "1":
    print("Hello")

else:
    print("Error")
```

How I keep run the program after else.
So How I do when I type something other than 1, it does say Error and again say Please type something. How how how :=)

I know my English is bad and I ask a lot of questions :(

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your code in an infinite loop, so that is iterated indefinitely:

```
while True:
    enter = input("Please type something: ")
    if enter == "1":
        print("Hello")
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Terminate your program by hitting CTRL+C on Linux/MacOS or CTRL+Z on Windows. If you want, you can use a word to terminate the program, like this:

```
while True:
    enter = input("Please type something: ")
    if enter == "1":
        print("Hello")
    elif enter == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Also, if you are using Python 2, then replace `input` with `raw_input`, so that what you type is returned verbatim as a string with the trailing new line stripped. See [PEP 3111](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/) for more information.

Comment: Also, he clarified he was using python 2, so input is actually correct. It is new to 33.

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor Your comments is misleading, please delete it.

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor, do I have to tell you that in Python you do not declare (you probably meant that, not "define") variables explicitly? Also, since the OP uses Python 2, `raw_input` _is_ correct.

Comment: @aIKid, I don't see how.

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor because they are plain wrong?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo, it says in his tag that he is using 3.x. And sorry, thanks for reminding me about the vat thing, I've been doing Java most recently.

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor You can define a variable anywhere. Either in a while loop, for loop, or an if statement.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Ah, he's actually right. In the tags, it's Python 3.x

Comment: @aIKid Actually the question is tagged both Python and Python3... Anyway I added the explanation for both and a link to the "`raw_input` to `input`" PEP.

Answer (score 0):

Stick it in a loop.

```
enter="0"
while True:
    enter = input("Please type something.")

    if enter == "1":
        print("hello")
    else:
        print("error")
```

This will keep running until you close the program.

Comment: The first assignment is not necessary.

Comment: You cannot create var in loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot.You saved my life too :=)
But Stefano is telling the truth so that worked well